# forwardfor information is missing

Tags: load-balancing, https, haproxy

I use following configuration to load balance https connections, using haproxy 1.4.8. SSL offloading is done by apache.

```
listen ssl_to_waf 192.168.101.54:443
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server wafA 192.168.101.61:444 check

listen ssl_from_waf 192.168.101.61:445
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server webA 192.168.101.46:80 check
```

For HTTP requests this works great, requests are distributed to my Apache servers just fine. But for HTTPS request, I lose the "forwardfor" information. I need to save the client IP address. How can I use HAproxy to load balance across a number of SSL servers, allowing those servers to know the client's IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

HAProxy doesn't understand SSL and hence balances these connections in TCP mode.  The `forwardfor` option doesn't mean anything in TCP mode as it is an HTTP header.

Everything I have read about SSL and HAProxy recommends using some other software *in front of* HAProxy to handle the SSL offloading.  Some of the suggestions were Pound and nginx however the valid point was raised that these are load-balancing proxy servers themselves and why would you introduce extra complexity and an extra hop when you could just have one of them handle the load-balancing and remove HAProxy entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to haproxy 1.5-dev12 and enable SSL offloading. Then the backend servers get an HTTP connection even when the client is using SSL. And since haproxy gets to see inside the SSL sessions it can add the forwardfor header.

Answer (score 0):

I would never suggest using dev software in production environments. I use nginx for ssl in front of ha proxy on the same machines. Works like a charm even under heavy loads. Your apache servers will get http traffic. You need to send the x-forwarded-for header to apache, then install the mod-rpaf module so apache can see the client ip. You may also need to set an apache env var so apps will know that the connection was in ssl.